# Angular Spinner With a Background

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-spinner module to load a spinner on every REST call , but the spinner just appears on center of screen, this makes the background of the page clickable.

How to make background opaque (not clickable), when the spinner is loading?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle for us?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following style for your spinner container:

```
.spinner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.spinner:before {
  background-color: $gray-lighter;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
}
```